# How to make a slider with dot and prev/next buttons just by using CSS

Tags: css, slider, css-animations

I have some problem in making a simple slider by pure CSS. I have already made a slider with dot buttons, now I want to make a prev/next buttons but the code doesn't work and I'm confused 
Here goes the HTML/CSS: https://codepen.io/Sethdash/pen/ZxLydr

```
 <article class="slide">
   <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide-1" checked='checked'>
      <label for="slide-1" class="label label-1"></label>

     <figure>
        <img src="1.jpg">
         <label class="prev" for="slide-1"><span>&#x2039</span></label>
      <label class="next" for="slide-3"><span>&#x203a</span></label> 
        <figcaption>expend your expedndiure with DRAKE 1
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
     </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major issues. 
1.) You can never click the prev/next labels because the figcaption is above it. When I removed the figcaption element, I could click the next button and have it work.
2.) The for attributes (in the prev/next labels) are wrong. For example, the for attribute for the prev label for the first article is 1, meaning that it would go to itself, so nothing happens. Also the for attribute for the next label for the first article is 3, so it skips a whole slide.

Comment: I fixed the logic in the prev/next labels, and removed the figcaption element but still the prev/next buttons in slide 2,3,4 is unclickable, or don't work properly. I think perhaps there is a condition behind it that I have to add in CSS ?